# How can you reference taxonomy term by another field in Yaml file?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, migrations

I created my own Yaml file with fields inside to migrate nodes.

I run into this problem.
If I use the feeds module, I can set (during mappings) that a given field (taxonomy term reference field) can be referenced by any other field from my site. The term name is therefore assigned based on the value in the reference field.

**If I use Migrate CSV module, how do I set this in Yaml file?**
This is my Yaml:

```
uuid: bf1e53ae-6a95-48f2-8888-4b928e6e33ea

id: testovacimigrace2
label: My own migration !!!!!!!
migration_group: migration

source:
  plugin: 'csv'
  # Full path to the file.
  path: 'modules/custom/migrace/assets/csv/upload1.csv'
  delimiter: ','
  enclosure: '"'
  header_row_count: 1
  ids:
    - ID

process:
  title: title
  field_email: email  
  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: submitlawyer 

destination:
  plugin: entity:node
```

1. Every term in my taxonomy called "fishes" has its own field with a unique number.
2. My CSV contains a column called fish that does not contain a term name but its unique number (ad.1)
3. I need to assign the correct term by using this unique number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple migration for looking up a taxonomy term by name based on the text in a CSV.

```
taxonomy_field_name:
  plugin: entity_lookup
  source: name_of_source_column
  value_key: name
  bundle_key: vid
  bundle: name_of_taxonomy
  entity_type: taxonomy_term
```

For example, if you have a taxonomy called `fishes`, and your CSV has a column called `fish`, and your node has a field called `field_fish` which is an entityreference to a taxonomy term of the `fishes` vocabulary, and there is a taxonomy term "Carp" with entity ID 14

```
field_fish:
  plugin: entity_lookup
  source: fish
  value_key: name
  bundle_key: vid
  bundle: fishes
  entity_type: taxonomy_term
```

Given a row in the CSV with "Carp" set as the fish, this will assign entity id 14 to that field.

Does that help?  I am not sure what you mean by "a given field can be referenced by any other field from my site".

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply, Steve.

Every term in my taxonomy called "fishes" has its own field with a unique number.

My CSV contains a column called fish that does not contain a term name but its unique number (ad.1)

I need to assign the correct term by using this unique number.

Comment: @Hefi if I understand you correctly now, you would change `value_key: name` to `value_key: field_unique_number` - where `field_unique_number` is the machine name of the field you added to those taxonomy terms

Comment: Yes, but "field_unique_number" value is only needed to assign a name of the given term.

But when i use the term field "field_unique_number" as a value_key, the terms are not associated with the node.

Comment: Just to confirm, you have actually added `field_unique_number` to the taxonomy bundle `fishes`, all terms within that vocabulary have that field, and it is populated?  So if you go to your term "Carp" in the `/admin/structure/taxonomy` area, you can see it definitely has a field_unique_number of, say, "22".  And you have definitely have 22 in the `fish` source column of your csv, and you've double checked that source column is correctly named, and the `field_fish` is correctly named with respect to the node, etc?  But when you run the migration it still fails to match?  If so... I'm stuck

Comment: @Hefi when you say "field unique number is only needed to assign a name", do you mean, you haven't actually created a field, and added it and populated it, because it's only needed during import and you don't want to clutter your database with that as a permanent field?  If so, perhaps the [static map plugin](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21migrate%21src%21Plugin%21migrate%21process%21StaticMap.php/class/StaticMap) is the answer.  It will allow you to set up a simple yaml mapping like `22: Carp` which you can feed down the pipeline to lookup taxon term by name.

Comment: Thank you, Steve.
I loaded wrong backup where "field_unique_number" was not populated.

It looks, it works now.
Just facing the "Killed" message during drush migration.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Great stuff, glad I could help.  Migrate is so frustrating sometimes, but powerful once you get it working!